# Задача на рекуррентное соотношение и количество операций

Tags: c++, ряды

Требуется решить две задачки:

1. Дано число *n* (количество элементов) и произвольное вещественное *a*. Необходимо найти сумму первых *n* элементов первых членов ряда:

   > *1 / a<sup>2</sup> + 3! / a<sup>4</sup> + 5! / a<sup>6</sup> + 7! / a<sup>8</sup> + ...*

   Решить нужно с обязательным использованием формулы рекуррентных соотношений.

   У меня формула получилась такая, но получается какая-то дичь при выполнении программы:

   ```
   f(i) = 1 / ((2 * i - 2) * (2 * i - 3) * a * a);
   ```
2. Дано вещественное число *х*. Не пользуясь никакими другими операциями, кроме умножения, сложения и вычитания, вычислить значения выражений:

   > *1 - 2x + 3x<sup>2</sup> - 4x<sup>3</sup>*

   и

   > *1 + 2x + 3x<sup>2</sup> + 4x<sup>3</sup>*

   Разрешается использовать не более восьми операций (это в сумме для обоих выражений). Допускается использовать только три дополнительные переменные (*х* не считается).

   Я просидел над задачей, но у меня при вынесении общего множителя всегда есть отличие на один знак.

   Мой набросок, нерабочий:

   ```
   float x, rez_one, rez_two, buf;
   pt >> x;
   buf = x * ((-x) * (4 * x - 3) - 2);
   rez_one = 1 + buf;
   rez_two = 1 - buf;
   pt << rez_one;
   pt << rez_two;
   ```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Второе проще пареной репы:

```
y = x*x;       // 1
z = 3*y+1;     // 2,3
t = (4*y+2)*x; // 4,5,6
y = z - t;     // 7
z = z + t;     //8
```

Значения - в `y` и `z`.

Первое - я бы исходил из общей формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тогда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну, или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]